# Ionic 2: Beta 8 - scrollable content area cutting off button at bottom

Tags: css, templates, typescript, angular, ionic2

**Q) Anyone know why my button is suddenly being cut off in the latest Ionic 2 Beta 8?**

**Note: When I comment out the `ion-toolbar` at the top, the button is then fully visible**

[image]

You can see that the button is partially visible on iOS but not at all on Android.

Here's my straightforward template HTML:

```
<ion-toolbar header-bg-buildings>    
  <ion-title>{{_I8nService.titles.addBuilding}}</ion-title>
  <ion-buttons start>
    <button (click)="cancel()">
      <span primary showWhen="ios">{{_I8nService.labels.cancel}}</span>
      <ion-icon name="md-close" showWhen="android,windows"></ion-icon>
    </button>
  </ion-buttons>  
</ion-toolbar>

<ion-toolbar danger *ngIf="showNoConnectionBar">
  <ion-title>{{_I8nService.titles.noConnection}}</ion-title>
</ion-toolbar>

<ion-content class="addBuilding">          
  ....        
  <ion-item-group>
    <ion-item-divider light>{{_I8nService.labels.signed}}:</ion-item-divider>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-card class="signed-card">
        <ion-card-content>
          <img src='{{currentUserSignature}}' />
        </ion-card-content>
      </ion-card>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-item-group>  

  <div>
      <button class="submit-button" full complete (click)="createBuilding()">{{_I8nService.labels.createBuilding}}</button>
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: Can you create a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/) just with that page? It will be easier to see what's going on there.

Comment: I did here, on my github issue:. https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/6839

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this makes no sense, but what happens if you replace that `div`

```
<div>
    <button full complete>Submit</button>
</div>
```

for a

```
<ion-toolbar position="bottom">
    <button full complete>Submit</button>
</ion-toolbar>
```

After all Ionic doc says that

> A Toolbar is a generic bar that is positioned above or below content

And maybe that could force the content to include the button avoiding the issue. Remember to put that new toolbar **inside the ion-content**. Tested on your plunker and works but honestly can not tell if it's going to work in your project.

The code would look like this:

```
<ion-toolbar>    
  <ion-title>Page 1</ion-title>
  <ion-buttons start>
    <button>
      <span primary showWhen="ios">cancel</span>
      <ion-icon name="md-close" showWhen="android,windows"></ion-icon>
    </button>
  </ion-buttons> 
</ion-toolbar>

<ion-content>

  <ion-item-group>
    <ion-item-divider light>Some group:</ion-item-divider>    
    <ion-row>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label stacked>field 1:</ion-label>
        <ion-input></ion-input>
      </ion-item> 
    </ion-row>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label stacked>field 2:</ion-label>
        <ion-input></ion-input>
      </ion-item> 
    </ion-row>    
  </ion-item-group>    

  <ion-item-group>
    <ion-item-divider light>Some group:</ion-item-divider>    
    <ion-row>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label stacked>field 1:</ion-label>
        <ion-input></ion-input>
      </ion-item> 
    </ion-row>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label stacked>field 2:</ion-label>
        <ion-input></ion-input>
      </ion-item> 
    </ion-row>    
  </ion-item-group>

  <ion-item-group>
    <ion-item-divider light>Some group:</ion-item-divider>    
    <ion-row>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label stacked>field 1:</ion-label>
        <ion-input></ion-input>
      </ion-item> 
    </ion-row>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label stacked>field 2:</ion-label>
        <ion-input></ion-input>
      </ion-item> 
    </ion-row>    
  </ion-item-group>

  <ion-item-group>
    <ion-item-divider light>Some group:</ion-item-divider>    
    <ion-row>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label stacked>field 1:</ion-label>
        <ion-input></ion-input>
      </ion-item> 
    </ion-row>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label stacked>field 2:</ion-label>
        <ion-input></ion-input>
      </ion-item> 
    </ion-row>    
  </ion-item-group>

  <ion-item-group>
    <ion-item-divider light>Some group:</ion-item-divider>    
    <ion-row>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label stacked>field 1:</ion-label>
        <ion-input></ion-input>
      </ion-item> 
    </ion-row>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label stacked>field 2:</ion-label>
        <ion-input></ion-input>
      </ion-item> 
    </ion-row>    
  </ion-item-group>  


  <ion-toolbar position="bottom">
    <button full complete>Submit</button>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: Thanks, I did actually try exactly that, but the result is exactly the same!  I have nothing else happening on that page (no code or CSS) that is changing the built in styles either.

Comment: Interestingly, I just added a blank toolbar underneath my submit button: `<ion-toolbar></ion-toolbar>`  ...and it 'fixed' the problem.  Leaving it!

Comment: Great, glad to hear that!. I was going to ask you what happened if you play a little bit with the height of the ion-content with something like 

`height: calc(100% - 44px)`

but nevermind. If that fix the issue, it may be a bug of ionic and how it calculates the height of the different components of the page.